# Link detection in a UITextView inside a UITableViewCell - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I have a chat app. The bubble chat inside a `UITableViewCell` is composed by a `UIImageView` (the bubble) and a `UITextView` created programmatically and it has `DataDetectorTypes` to detect phone numbers and links. When I have the link in the beginning of the text or the link alone in the cell everything works perfectly, but my problem is when the link is at the end of the `UITextView`. It gets detect as a link but the click on the link doesn't work.

I have created the `UITextView` like that:

```
[self.messageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.messageLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
[self.messageLabel setText:nil];
[self.messageLabel setEditable:NO];
[self.messageLabel setSelectable:YES];
[self.messageLabel setScrollEnabled:NO];
[self.messageLabel setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
[self.messageLabel setDataDetectorTypes:(UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber|UIDataDetectorTypeLink)];
[self.messageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check the messageLabel and its superview frames to see if the superview has a smaller frame, then the touch will not be received by the messageLabel.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the cell ContentView height.. the cell height was right but the content was always 44.0! thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try again after increase row height of a cell in `[tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath].`

If it works, you need to change of height of cell dynamically.

Comment: The problem was the cell ContentView height.. the cell height was right but the content was always 44.0! thanks for your answer!